# How to write unit test for getPopularItems()?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

The **Item** can be viewed by visitor, the **viewed counter** will be saved in database table(e.g. Items table). 
So getPopularItems() is to get the most viewed items, according to the **viewed counter** of items.

The problem is:

**What should I check** in test case for getPopularItems()?

Since getPopularItems() get most viewed items according to the viewed counter, If I use this method again to get most viewed items in testGetPopularItems() and check if these two collections(popular items) are equal, isn't it duplication?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using php with cakephp framework, and the unit testing framework is phpunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test that `getPopularItems()` returns nothing as long as no item has been viewed.

Then you could test that it returns something while one item has been viewed.

Then after a larger amount of visits over a larger amount of items you could test that it returns the maximum number of popular items the function should return (Boundary Tests).

Just test the logic inside that function, don't test that running the same function twice will return the same (which often is the case even there is an error in the code, so you would only test if the function executes, for which you would only need to call it once).

Comment: Thanks a lot! (Just test the logic inside that function)